# Trouble with JSON response & bootstrap-ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap-ajax plugin found here and I may be making some very basic beginner mistakes:  [bootstrap-ajax](https://github.com/eldarion/bootstrap-ajax/blob/master/README.md)

I have a very basic form consisting of a submit button that is supposed to perform a GET request to an external page and then update a specified div from the JSON response of that external page.

```
<div class="done-score" data-refresh-url="ajaxrefreshdiv.php">
Refresh Div
</div>

<div class="done-list">
Append Div
</div>

<a 
href="ajaxrefreshdiv.php" 
class="btn ajax" data-method="GET"
data-append=".done-list"
data-refresh=".done-score"
>

<i class="icon icon-check">
</i>
Done
</a>
```

And on the external php page I have the following code:

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '
        [{"html":"THIS IS MY TEST"}]
     ';
?>
```

I also tried echoing out:

```
var data = {"html":"This is a test"};
```

From all the examples I've seen and tutorials I've watched this appeared to be the proper way to respond but the string is not being displayed on the page, nor does the spinner stop spinning (like it is still waiting for a confirmation that the page has responded).  The refresh div does however remove the intial text and update to an empty div so I know that the refreshing is working correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

I have verified that the problem is definitely my formating of the json response.  I was able to create an array using php and then echo out that array using json_encode and the value of my "html" key is now displaying in the divs.

```
$data=array(
'html' => '<div class="row-fluid">THIS IS MY TEST</div>'
);
echo json_encode($data)
;
```

However the spinner is still spinning as if the script is still waiting on some type of verification as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my questions.  Just in case anyone else comes across the same problems here is the solutions:

**Problems with divs not updating or refreshing** (at least in this particular case) were due to incorrect formatting of the json response.

**Problem with div containing initial button or form disappearing or spinner continually spinning:**
After looking through the source code of a working example I realized that you have to send back a fragment array containing the html code to be refreshed for the div that contains the ajax button or ajax form.

Comment: Would you post the working example, I am running into the same issue